# Swift: NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData() fails with JSON utf-8

Tags: ios, json, swift, utf-8

My iOS app needs to download some data from a DBMS MySQL which is utf-8 encoded, for example:

```
{"id":"1","id_fish":"5","description_info":"Come ricorda il nome, la colorazione del carapace di questo gambero \u00e9 rosa chiaro, che si fa pi\u00f9 intensa sul dorso. Il corpo \u00e8 leggermente compresso lateralmente e possiede 13 paia di zampe. Raggiunge la lunghezza di 18 cm. Si riproduce in primavere e autunno. ","recognition_info":"La forma del gambero rosa \u00e8 molto simile agli altri decapodi come gambero rosso e lo scampo. Si possono per\u00f2 facilmente differenziare in base alle dimensioni e al colore.","place_info":"Oceano Atlantico, tra Portogallo e Angola e tra Massachusetts e Guyana, e Mar Mediterraneo.","fishing_method":"Rete a strascico","buy_period":"Estate - Inverno"}
```

and here's the code:

```
if let responseJSON: [[String: String]] = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())) as? [[String: String]] {
                completionHandler(success: responseJSON, error:nil)
            }

            else {
                print("Error coding!")
            }
```

As you can imagine, it always says "Error coding" while if the downloaded JSON is simply ASCII than everything works well.
What am I missing?

The content of `data` with `print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))` is:

```
Optional({"id":"1","id_fish":"5","description_info":"Come ricorda il nome, la colorazione del carapace di questo gambero \u00e9 rosa chiaro, che si fa pi\u00f9 intensa sul dorso. Il corpo \u00e8 leggermente compresso lateralmente e possiede 13 paia di zampe. Raggiunge la lunghezza di 18 cm. Si riproduce in primavere e autunno. ","recognition_info":"La forma del gambero rosa \u00e8 molto simile agli altri decapodi come gambero rosso e lo scampo. Si possono per\u00f2 facilmente differenziare in base alle dimensioni e al colore.","place_info":"Oceano Atlantico, tra Portogallo e Angola e tra Massachusetts e Guyana, e Mar Mediterraneo.","fishing_method":"Rete a strascico","buy_period":"Estate - Inverno"})
```

I use `utf8_encode()` in the php file!

Comment: How did you get "data!"?

Comment: Can you include a log of what exactly is contained in `data`? I suspect broken JSON from your data source.

Comment: @JanGreve done, added to my question

Comment: Can you just check with ----  options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments, as your json is in dictionary.

Comment: Can you feed that data to a NSString constructor, see what happens? Php has some problems with UTF8;)

Comment: @JanGreve The string is fine, the encoding is fine, the type is wrong.

Comment: @vadian yeah, I noticed your answer and upped it already. Totally missed that one.

Comment: Forgive me for my late...today everything is a mess. I have just updated my answer...so what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON object is a dictionary `[String: String]` rather than an array `[[String: String]]`.

I recommend to use the `do - catch` block

```
do {
   let responseJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as! [String: String]
   completionHandler(success: responseJSON, error:nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
   completionHandler(success: nil, error:error)
}
```